# Looking for reliable wireless printer for redistribution

Tags: wireless, printer

We make devices that capture and handle sensor data. Our base unit is a wireless dock that charges our specialized tablet, and has two inputs (DC voltage and Ethernet (RJ-45)), no outputs, disregarding the built in wireless access point. Now we need a printer to distribute that can print out this data.

What we need is a wireless printer that is above all reliable (in connecting as in printing) and relatively easy to set up - without connecting it to a computer first (should it come to that, we might consider a one-time USB connection, but would rather avoid it).

Color printing is requested, but not necessary, size does matter - the smaller the better. Speed should be above at least 10 ppm.

Thermal printers are to be avoided if possible, but not at all costs.

I've looked across a lot of printers, but can barely find any with reliable reviews - so I would like to hear from those of you that actually own/produce/distribute such a printer.

Quick recap:

- Wifi connection
- Configurable without a PC connection (SD card, NFC, USB, doesn't matter, so long as it is as simple as possible. We can preconfigure our wireless AP.)
- Color or BW printing
- As small as possible
- Extremely reliable
- To be mass produced for a while, so we can include it with our products.

Thank you for your input.

Matija